# How to use Cat in proc sql macro?

Tags: proc-sql

I would like to use macro with macro variable in its name like this for example:

```
%let column1 = "XYZ"n;
%let column2 = "ZXY"n;
%let column_number = 1;

proc sql; create table abc
as select &cats("column","&column_number")
where column = column_number
;quit;
```

That means, that I would like to use the number in calling the macro variable, but also using it elsewhere in the code. It means just changing the column_number, and selecting which macro variable to use.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is not tested, but it may fit your need:
I made column_number into an argument for the macro "Test". A double ampersand makes it so the first read through skips the macro variable column, and defines macro column_number first, so when the macro variable column is read it makes sense. Sometimes the quotes around column_number at the end may not be necessary, it depends on your data type for column_number.

```
%let column1 = "XYZ"n;
%let column2 = "ZXY"n;

%macro Test (column_number);
proc sql; create table abc
as select &&column.&column_number
where column = "&column_number"
;quit;
%mend Test;
%Test (column_number=1);
%Test (column_number=2);
```